# Problems with video recording logic; filling empty frame and synchronizing fps

Tags: algorithm, video, video-streaming, video-recording

I got some problems with my video recording logic.
My recording algorithm is below as pseudo code.

```
fps = 30
msPerFrame = 1000 / fps
videoRecorder = VideoRecorder(fps)
timer.start()
while (true) {
  if ((timer.elapsed() >= msPerFrame) && (newFrame.isReady() == true)) {
    videoRecorder.push(newFrame)
    timer.restart()
  }
}
```

Note that the `videoRecorder` determines the fps of the video file as soon as it is created and starts recording.
The problem is below:

1. What is the best way to handle when `(timer.elapsed() >= msPerFrame) && (newFrame.isReady() == false)`? If I just wait for a frame to be ready, this gap is recorded at `fps` despite being larger than the actual `msPerFrame`.
2. How to calibrate recording fps error? If `fps=30`, `msPerFrame=33.3333...`. However, the `timer.elapsed()` returns milliseconds value so `timer.elapsed() >= msPerFrame` may true when `msPerFrame >= 34`. So the 30 `newFrame`s at 1020 milliseconds are pushed to 1000 milliseconds of resulting video.

Comment: I'm not the one to Answer your question but... **(1)** _"This gap is recorded at fps"_ not sure what type of function/Class is `videoRecorder but it needs to be coded to wait and then write/record (to the "output" bytes) when only a new frame is given. Not obvious what video codec your output is encoded into.

Comment: **(2)** Is there no `toPrecision` option to use with Timer? Otherwise you need an alternate Timer/Stopwatch API that has microseconds. Maybe simply treat `33.333` as a single `33` and account for the fact that every 3 frames adds 1 extra second to time. Otherwise just use a different frame rate that works in non-fractions like 25fps (where `msPerFrame=40`)

Comment: PS:  Oops I meant every 3 frames adds 1 extra **millisecond** to the output duration time.

Comment: @VC.One I solved the problem (1) and wrote it as answer below, still hollow, but works pretty fine. Thanks for your inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

I simply solved the question (1) using frame buffer which contains `newFrame` as FIFO order. The recorder now references the last frame of the frame buffer when needing to push the frame to the recording buffer. So, if `newFrame` is not ready when `timer.elapsed() >= msPerFrame`, then the recorder push the last frame one more.

```
bufferMaxSize = MAX_BUF_SIZE
frameBuffer
isRecording = false

// This callback is called when newFrame is ready.
callbackFunction(newFrame) {
  frameBuffer.push(newFrame) // Push to the back of the buffer
  while (frameBuffer.size() > MAX_BUF_SIZE)
    frameBuffer.pop() // Remove front of the buffer
}

startRecordingFunction() {
  fps = 30
  msPerFrame = 1000 / fps
  videoRecorder = VideoRecorder(fps)
  timer.start()

  while (isRecording) {
    if (timer.elapsed() >= msPerFrame) {
      videoRecorder.push(frameBuffer.back())
      timer.restart()
    }
  }

  videoRecorder.save("video.mp4")
}
```

Plus, the thread running `startRecordingFunction()` is critical for time, so giving higher job priority of that thread gave me more stable result.